# Updating a tileset recipe always generates 400 Bad Request

Tags: mapbox

Has anyone got this to work?  https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#update-a-tilesets-recipe

```
curl -X PATCH "https://api.mapbox.com/tilesets/v1/{tileset}/recipe?access_token=YOUR MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN
This endpoint requires a token with tilesets:write scope.
" \
  -d @recipe.json \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Using the same recipe I used initially I always get error:
400 Bad Request: {"errors":["Recipe has no version."],"message":"Recipe is invalid."}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error then realized that `version` was not at the root level of my object. I adjusted the content of my recipe.json file to be like this and things started working.

```
{"version": 1, "layers": {"my_layer": {"source": "mapbox://tileset-source/username/tileset", "minzoom": 0, "maxzoom": 5}}}
```